# Execute normal command over range

Tags: command-line, normal-mode, repeated-commands

For a file looking like this:

```
   2  AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
   3  AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
   4  AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
   5  AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
```

I am trying to remove the leading spaces and numbers for the first 10 lines, so I'd end up with

```
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,376
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,971
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,93
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,1
```

Why does "remove two words" `:d2w` work for a single line, but not for a range `:1,10d2w`?

NOTE:

The problem itself is solved due to the fixed format, using `:1,10s/.\{8\}//`, so this is more about understanding how to use ranges with `:dNw`

Comment: Also: `:1,10s/\v^(\s|\d)*/` (remove any number of spaces or digits at the start of the first 10 lines)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this with the normal command :

```
:1,10normal d2w
```

This is because the `d` operator doesn't accept a range, but only a motion :

```
:h d

["x]d{motion}           Delete text that {motion} moves over [into register x].
```

Alternatively you can select your text in visual mode and you can do :

```
:'<,'>normal d2w
```

Comment: sorry for explicitly asking: `:normal` will allow to execute the command as if I would enter it when navigating with the cursor?

Comment: `:normal` allows you to execute a command as it was entered  in normal mode (when you navigate the cursor with `hjkl`). See : `:h :normal`

Comment: The colons in front of normal after the range are redundant.