# make u (undo) also reset . (repeat last command)?

Tags: repeated-commands, undo-redo

Sometimes I make a change, then in my scramble to move to somewhere else that I want to repeat the change, I accidentally make some edit (e.g. `ill`).

I would normally undo the accidental edit with `u`, but now I can't use `.` anymore to repeat my last meaningful change, my intended change.

Is there a way I can preserve the last *meaningful* change I made? Either, have `u` revert the last command stored in `.`, or save myself from accidental edits differently.

I know that 100% of the time I use `u`, unless my last command was `.`, then the command I undo with `u` should also not be repeated by `.`.

I already know I can use macros to repeat changes, so I am looking for solutions that will work for commands I executed without recording them into macros.

Comment: There's no built in/accessible storage of Normal mode command history. No easy path by custom script either. Different question but touching on some related ground: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15713/save-last-action-in-a-macro

Comment: If someone were to, say, write a plugin for this it might involve setting up persistent storage of`-w`/`-W` output. There might be an answer here that talks about that....I seem to recall. But that's going to be a non-trivial amount of work.